# Magento mirasvit sphinx search module is not working with mana layered navigation module

Tags: search, navigation, sphinx, layered

I am using magento community version 1.9 and I have integrated mirasvit sphinx search extension but it is not working with Layered Navigation module.
I am filtering search result with Mana layered Navigation 
but it is still showing me the same result.
It is not applying the layered navigation filter on search result.
When I am removing this mirasvit extension and applying filter with default search module it is working fine.
Would request you please provide help for me.

Thanks
Zahid

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered on both provider's site:

- Manadev https://www.manadev.com/documentation/magento-1.x-guides/seo-layered-navigation-plus/troubleshooting/extension---mirasvit-search-index
- Mirasvit https://mirasvit.com/doc/ssu/2.3.4/troubleshooting

> There is a known conflict with the extension Mana_Fitlers. Error may occur on the search result page, when trying to apply filters.
>
> **Solution:**
>
> 1 - app/design/frontend/[YOUR PACKAGE]/[YOUR THEME]/layout/catalogsearch.xml -
>    find and comment out everything inside  `<reference name="content">` under `<catalogsearch_result_index>` as shown below:
>
> ```
> <catalogsearch_result_index>
>     ...
>     <reference name="content">
>         <!-- COMMENT EVERYTHING IN IT -->
>     </reference>
>     ...
> </catalogsearch_result_index>
> ```
>
> 2 - app/etc/modules/Mirasvit_SearchIndex.xml – make sure that this module loads before our module by adding dependency on the Mana_Filters module:
>
> ```
> <config>
>        <modules>
>            <Mirasvit_SearchIndex>
>                <active>true</active>
>                <codePool>local</codePool>
>            </Mirasvit_SearchIndex>
>            <Mana_Filters>
>                <depends>
>                    <Mirasvit_SearchIndex/>
>                </depends>
>            </Mana_Filters>
>        </modules>
>    </config>
> ```